# Lorentz group in SUSY

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, supersymmetry, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

Why do we carry Lorentz group to be included also in supersymmetry? That is after we extend our symmetry to supersymmetry, we carry with us the Lorentz group. Why not other group instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Haag-Lopuszanski-Sohnius (HLS) theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haag%E2%80%93Lopuszanski%E2%80%93Sohnius_theorem) yields a preference for the [super-Poincare algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincar%C3%A9_algebra). When the assumptions of the HLS theorem are not fulfilled, other non-trivial extensions of the spacetime Poincare algebra is possible, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83781/2451) Phys.SE post.